# Will a vasectomy prevent genetic engineering of a child?

Tags: human-genetics

Making the assumption:

> Within 10 years, an adult will be able to genetically engineer (modify, enhance, clean, etc.) a child from their own DNA (and the DNA of a non-related partner).

then would getting a vasectomy today preclude this?

Answer (score 3):

From the wording of your question the 'genetic engineering' that you are envisaging will involve sperm. So the question is really, does vasectomy affect sperm production?

The answer is that it does, but it doesn't abolish it. For example:

> McVicar et al. (2005) Effects of vasectomy on spermatogenesis and fertility outcome after testicular sperm extraction combined with ICSI. Human Reproduction 20: 2795-2800

These authors found that sperm yield fell to about 35% > 5 years post-vasectomy.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't mean to imply that sperm or an egg need to be involved, just DNA.

Comment: DNA from which cells?